# JMVC: steal/buildjs - Build is throwing error "failed to open file file:/profile/getPolicy

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascriptmvc

The "file" in question is actually an Ajax call.  We are getting almost one error per every ajax call in a particular file.  We use to have fixtures turned on, but have since then removed them.

Error:

```
failed to open file  file:/profile/getPolicy   JavaException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /profile/getPolicy (No such file or directory) 
Exception in thread "Thread-2" org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "indexOf" of null (steal/rhino/env.js#24532)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3654)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3632)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3660)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3679)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefCallError(ScriptRuntime.java:3698)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2221)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2214)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:3143)
    at script(steal/rhino/env.js:24532)
    at script(steal/rhino/env.js:2278)
    at script.makeRequest(steal/rhino/env.js:24484)
    at script(steal/rhino/env.js:2027)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:2487)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:164)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:398)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3065)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:162)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Synchronizer.call(Synchronizer.java:79)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Runner.run(Global.java:1162)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:515)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Runner.run(Global.java:1156)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
could not load script  http://localhost:3000/socket.io/1/?t=1334594888337&jsonp=0  
  TypeError: Cannot find function 0.0. 
!!!!!!!!!!! ERROR !!!!!!!!!!!

-message    = Cannot find function 0.0.
-fileName   = http://localhost:3000/socket.io/1/?t=1334594888337&jsonp=0
-name       = TypeError
-lineNumber = 0
failed to open file  file:/profile/getProfile   JavaException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /profile/getProfile (No such file or directory) 
Exception in thread "Thread-4" org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "indexOf" of null (steal/rhino/env.js#24532)
```

As you can see the next error is related to the next ajax call.  We aren't doing anything strange with our ajax calls:

```
$.ajax({
        url:"/profile/getProfile",
        type:"get",
        success:function(data){
            try{
                STATE.PROFILE = JSON.parse(data);
            }catch(err){
                STATE.PROFILE = data;
            }
            updateState();
        }
    });
```

Does anyone have any idea why we are getting these errors when we try to build?  This code runs fine in the browser!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brian, you were correct after all, in the fact that removing the Ajax calls does remove the errors from the build.  Although the wording has changed.  One of our developers found the mention of "steal.isRhino" on the following page:
http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!migrate

So encapsulating every ajax call with an if statement does work:

```
  if(!steal.isRhino) {
  }
```

However that is not feasible across an application.  **Fortunately, one of our developers did find the proper solution:**

All ajax calls must have a full url:
http://localhost:3000/profile/getProfile - NOT JUST - /profile/getProfile

Comment: Cool. How will you handle this when you deploy the site and your root url (presumably) changes?

Comment: That is a good question.  Fortunately for us, we are deploying in an environment that we'll control completely.  So it won't be a problem. Although I can see that it could be a headache in other situations.  So at that point, we would probably define host variables in a central config file.